How old is cooperation between British and American parties on the same 'side'?
Recently there was a news story about Labour activists from the UK volunteering to support the Democratic party in the United States. Sometimes the traffic is the other way - in 2015 a team organised by the US Young Republicans International Committee  volunteered for the Tories in the election of that year.
How far back does this cooperation go? I'm asking about cooperation between the parties, rather than individual relationships between leaders.
In Britain the Tories have always been the rightwing party and their main opponent - Liberal then Labour - has always been the leftwing party. In the United States the division between the leftwing and the rightwing party was not as clear until the 1940s or so. Is that when the relationships began?

FWTW, one historian

pointed to former Conservative prime minister Margaret Thatcher’s use of pollsters who had worked for Republican president Ronald Reagan as one of the earliest examples of US strategists landing on British shores.
[...] “In the mid-Noughties the Republicans gave the Conservatives their “Voter Vault” software — software which allowed them to collect and organize huge amounts of voter data, with records of canvas returns and postcodes,” said Scammell [political scientist at the London School of Economics who specializes in campaigning and the Americanization of global politics]. “You can use that to identify people who may be amenable to your message.”

It's perhaps not quite the same as activists, but relevant enough, perhaps.

Yes it's relevant, thank you. It would be interesting to know if there was cooperation before this
